# Replace one word in searched result vim

Tags: vim, replace

Is it possible to replace a section in the searched result? for example I have currently

`<stringProp name="Argument.name">revision_no</stringProp>
 <stringProp name="Argument.value">1</stringProp>`

I want to replace the number (1) with ${var} on the 2nd line, and all other information remains the same.

If I type

```
:%s/revision_no<.*\n.*value">[0-9]\*/revision_no<(all the characters...) value">${var}/g
```

I might lose all the format(indentation involved)..

So I am wondering if there is a way to just replace "1" with ${var} in the whole search result.
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *capture* the other matching text (that you want to keep), and then reference that exact text in the replacement. The `\(...\)` is a *capture group* (`:help /\(`), and `\1` references it (the first such group) in the replacement. This is the traditional way, and it also works in `sed` and many other regular expression-based tools:

```
:%s/\(revision_no<.*\n.*value">\)[0-9]\+/\1${var}/g
```

Alternatively, in Vim, you can assert that certain surrounding stuff matches without actually including it in the match. This "cutting" is done via `\zs` (start match here) and `\ze` (end match here):

```
:%s/revision_no<.*\n.*value">\zs[0-9]\+/${var}/g
```

Comment: Thanks! You seem to be new to Vim. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.